# What breed of goats make babbling noises and spits?

Tags: breeds, goats

1. [first video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/TZMYt13UneA).
2. [second video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/eE5WQLMwHHk)

Both of the above are babbling and spitting at people.

Are they the same breeds? Are they north American breeds? What breed of goats are these?

What breeds do babble and spit on people in Europe and Asia?

Comment: Wikipedia article about [talking animals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talking_animal): "It is not unusual for goats to make noises that sound like syllables from human words. Some videos of this behavior have ended up becoming popular on YouTube. An example from Tennessee of a baby goat seeming to say "what what what?" got over seven million views." - So "speaking" seems not depending onto the breed.

Comment: Each lamb we ever raised by hand had a very distinct voice, I could tell them apart in the dark. One was even named “Elvis” because of the similar intonation. And they sometimes do sound pretty “human-like”, because they make a lot more sounds than the standard “baaaaah”. So expect that from many breeds of goats and sheep. The spitting doesn’t look intentional, rather like a side effect of the animal’s vocalizing and possibly distress.